# how to automate popup dialog window using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to  automate some report. When clicked on some element it will open popup dialog window but I won't get an access elements from it. Because, code will be running at parent window it can't go to the newly opened popup dialog window and when I closed the browser I got an error, but I won't get any message in the console.

I used the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gvWS_ctl01_ImageButton1")).click(); \\after click on this button, I won't get an access an element of popup 
dialog window and code will be running at this statement only

driver.switchTo().frame("Weather Upload");           
driver.switchTo().activeElement();          
driver.findElement(By.id("WeatherUploadData1_btnUpload")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

U can access popup's using alert function, below is the sample code how to do it.

```
    Alert prompt = driver.switchTo().alert();

    // Get message in Alert pop up
    message = prompt.getText();
    System.out.println("Prompt pop up message :- " + message);

    // Force the program to wait to view the dialog box
    try{Thread.sleep(4000);}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}

    // Type value in prompt dialog box
    prompt.sendKeys("Akshay Kumar");

    // Force the program to wait to view the dialog box
    try{Thread.sleep(4000);}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}

    // Click on Ok button
    prompt.accept();
```

Please let me know if this works out !

Comment: you dont know if the popup is an alert or an html page, the op should specify that

Answer (score 0):

You will need to switch to popup before selecting any element from pop up

```
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = windowHandles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   String handle = iterator.next();
   if (!handle.contains(parentWindow)) {
        // Switch to popup and close it
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        // Perform required action in popup
   }
}
// Switching back to parent window
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```